# What does "::int[]" means at the SQL line below?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to understand a SQL line code at a RoR app. Does anybody know what ::int[] means? It appears at each "case" after "and".

```
        case
        when (array_length(array_remove(company_profiles.blocked_trails_ids,null),1) IS NOT NULL) and array[trails.id]::int[] && array_remove(company_profiles.blocked_trails_ids,null) then
          false
        else
          true
        end and
        case
        when (array_length(array_remove(company_profiles.blocked_components_ids,null),1) IS NOT NULL) and array[components.id]::int[]&& array_remove(company_profiles.blocked_components_ids,null) then
          false
        else
          true
        end and
        case
        when (array_length(array_remove(company_profiles.blocked_academies_ids,null),1) IS NOT NULL) and array[academies.id]::int[] && array_remove(company_profiles.blocked_academies_ids,null) then
          false
        else
          true
        end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, every data type has a companion array type. If you define your own data type, PostgreSQL creates a corresponding array type in the background for you. For example, integer has an integer array type integer[], character has a character array type character[], and so forth.

The `::` is a type cast, a conversion from one data type to another.

---

Notice this line `array[components.id]::int[]&& array_remove(...)` might not work as expected.